# ActionMode color changed in Support Lib v22

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-actionmode

Recently I upgraded to support lib v22.1 from v21.0.3, the ActionMode used to work perfectly on v21.0.3. It still works great on Lollipop, but it doesn't work properly on Pre-L devices.

After the update, here's how it looks on Android Lollipop

[image]

And here's how it looks on Kitkat

[image: ActionMode on Kitkat]

Below is the theme I use

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And the toolbar in the Activity XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

**P.S.** Same problem on v22.0.0

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround is to manually set the action mode background in your style. Adding the following lines fixed a very similar issue in my project:

```
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/dark_blue</item> <!-- 5.0 -->
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/dark_blue</item> <!-- 4.4 and before -->
```